# Make inference from Vertex AI endpoint

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, yolo, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I have trained a YOLOv8 model and deployed it to Vertex AI, with the following signature

```
! saved_model_cli show --dir "runs/detect/train72/weights/best_saved_model" --tag_set serve --signature_def serving_default
```

```
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
  inputs['images'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_FLOAT
      shape: (1, 3, 960, 960)
      name: serving_default_images:0
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
  outputs['output0'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_FLOAT
      shape: (1, 6, 18900)
      name: StatefulPartitionedCall:0
Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict
```

Now, I would like to know how to make an inferences to it from an image stored in my Bucket input_bucket/image.png.

For starters I've tried running this code

```
im_test = cv2.imread(im_test_path)
image = cv2.cvtColor(im_test, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    # Resize the image to match the model's expected input size
image = cv2.resize(image, (960, 960))
#image = image / 255.0

    # Change data type to float32
image = image.astype(np.float32)
image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)  # Add the batch dimension

# Transpose the image to have the channel dimension as specified in the model
image = np.transpose(image, (0, 3, 1, 2))  # From NHWC to NCHW
print(image.shape)
encoded_image = numpy_array_to_base64(image)


instance = {"images": encoded_image}
instances = [instance]
client_options = {"api_endpoint": api_endpoint}
    # Initialize client that will be used to create and send requests.
    # This client only needs to be created once, and can be reused for multiple requests.
client = aiplatform.gapic.PredictionServiceClient(client_options=client_options)
parameters = predict.params.ImageObjectDetectionPredictionParams(
        confidence_threshold=0.5,
        max_predictions=5,
    ).to_value()
endpoint = client.endpoint_path(
        project=project, location=location, endpoint=endpoint_id
    )
response = client.predict(
        endpoint=endpoint, instances=instances, parameters=parameters
    )
```

but it gives me this error

```
FailedPrecondition: 400 The request size (14745946 bytes) exceeds 1.500MB limit.
```

Is my original code correct? Is my only problem image size?

Comment: Did you try with a smaller image size?

Answer (score 0):

It is a image size limitation of Vertex AI Endpoints, as you can check [here](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/image-data/classification/prepare-data) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/image-data/classification/prepare-data).

you can try resizing your image before sending to the model endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems on the right track, but the error you're encountering indicates that the size of the request you're sending to the model **exceeds the allowed limit of 1.5MB**. This is likely due to the large size of the image data you're trying to pass for inference.

When preparing your image for inference, it appears that you're encoding the image as **base64**, which might be increasing its size significantly. Instead of encoding the entire image as base64, you might want to consider sending the image data without encoding it as base64.

Remove this syntax:
`encoded_image = numpy_array_to_base64(image)`

Then, you can add this line of code:

```
instance = {"images": image.tolist()}  # Converting to list to avoid excessive data size
```

instead of `instance = {"images": encoded_image}`.